# Rhombi and Sides

Tags: geometry

I got a question, and am unable to solve it.

> $BA$ and $CA$ of $\Delta ABC$ are extended through $A$ to form rhombuses $BATR$ and $CAKN$. $BN$ and $RC$, intersecting at $P$, meet $AB$ and $AC$ at $S$ and $M$ respectively. Draw $MQ$ parallel to $AB$. Prove that $AMQS$ is a rhombus and $[BPC]=[ASPM]$.

Here's the diagram I made.

[image]

It seems that $RAN$ is a straight line, but I can't see how that's useful. Can anyone give me any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT.

For the first part, start by proving by similitude that
$$
AS=AM={AB\cdot AC\over AB+AC}.
$$
The second part is the same as proving that $[ABM]+[ACS]=[ABC]$, which can be done making use of the above result:
$$
{[ABM]\over[ABC]}+{[ACS]\over[ABC]}={AM\over AC}+{AS\over AB}=
{AB\over AB+AC}+{AC\over AB+AC}=1.
$$